# Cutting a substring within a string of variable depth with UNIX

Tags: string, unix, cut

I'm trying to parse out a part of a DNA sequence from a larger string using UNIX and cannot figure out how to parse out a substring from a larger string when the depth is not defined. As an example:

AGTCATGTACTACTCCGT**AAAAAAAA**GTCG

AGTCATGTACTACTCGT**AAAAAAAA**GTCG

AGTCATGTACTACTCCCCGT**AAAAAAAA**GTCG

In these three strings, I would like to pull out the strings of A's, but at each line the depth changes, so my typical route of cut -c will not work because the depth is varying.

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The depth changes, but what about the length?  If, not try sed

Comment: The length can change too, but if I assume a constant length what would an example sed syntax look like?

Comment: sed -r 's/A{6}//' file, this would remove 6 A's found anywhere in the line.